# Using numerical columns to name non-numerical columns (idk if that makes sense)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table that includes 2 columns. One has values from 1-12 and the other is all NA. I would like to write code so that, if a row contains the numbers 1,2,3,4,11,12 in the numerical column, the other column reads "Winter". If a row contains the numbers 5,6,7,8, "Summer", and 9,10, "Fall". How would I do this in R?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:12 , y = NA)
df
#>     x  y
#> 1   1 NA
#> 2   2 NA
#> 3   3 NA
#> 4   4 NA
#> 5   5 NA
#> 6   6 NA
#> 7   7 NA
#> 8   8 NA
#> 9   9 NA
#> 10 10 NA
#> 11 11 NA
#> 12 12 NA

df$y <- ifelse(df$x %in% c(1,2,3,4,11,12) ,
"Winter" , ifelse(df$x %in% c(9,10) ,"Fall" ,"Summer" ))

df
#>     x      y
#> 1   1 Winter
#> 2   2 Winter
#> 3   3 Winter
#> 4   4 Winter
#> 5   5 Summer
#> 6   6 Summer
#> 7   7 Summer
#> 8   8 Summer
#> 9   9   Fall
#> 10 10   Fall
#> 11 11 Winter
#> 12 12 Winter
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>